# Change button appearance when scrolling screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to change expandLabel (from my `ContextualHelpFloatingButton, expandLabel: MutableState<Boolean>`) when the user scroll or not the screen. In case of scrolling, expandLabel should be `false` and when user stop scrolling, should be `true`. I've had implemented `mutableStateOf()` and `rememberLazyListState()` but It won't work as I expected:

```
 @Composable
 private fun FruitDetailView(fruit: FruitModel?, items: List<FruitDetailItem>) {

        var expanded by remember {
            mutableStateOf(true)
        }
        val listState = rememberLazyListState()

        LaunchedEffect(remember { derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset } }) {
            expanded = listState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset == 0
        }

        Box {
            LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(UiColors.White)
                    .fillMaxHeight()
            ) {

               ...
            }
            Box(
                contentAlignment = Alignment.BottomEnd,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(vertical = 100.dp, horizontal = 20.dp)
            ){
                ContextualHelpFloatingButton(
                    accessibility = accessibility,
                    data = data,
                    interaction = ContextualHelpFloatingButtonInteraction(
                        expandLabel = remember {
                            mutableStateOf(expanded)
                        }
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to show the button **while no scrolling is currently happening**, you can use the following code:

```
val expanded = remember {
    mutableStateOf(true)
}
val listState = rememberLazyListState()    

expanded.value = !listState.isScrollInProgress
```

Have a look at the documentation of [`LazyListState`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListState).

Additionally, you have to change your `ContextualHelpFloatingButton` like this:

```
ContextualHelpFloatingButton(
    accessibility = accessibility,
    data = data,
    interaction = ContextualHelpFloatingButtonInteraction(
        expandLabel = expanded
    )
)
```

Also make sure that you are assigning `listState` to the [`LazyColumn`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#LazyColumn(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListState,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.FlingBehavior,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function1)) properly:

```
LazyColumn(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(UiColors.White)
        .fillMaxHeight(),
    state = listState
) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Hi @BenjyTec. Thanks for answer. Actually, I've already read the documentation but still not finding the solution. Besides, the button should be expanded when the screen isn't scrolling, the position doesn't matter.

Comment: Still not working... Besides, expandLabel is `MutableState<Boolean>` but, even solving that, `listState` has always the same value when I Log it. It's like It isn't aiming correctly when listening to the scroll...

Comment: Are you assigning the `listState` to the LazyColumn? Check out the updated answer.

Comment: IT'S ALIVE!! Works! Due to expandlLabel is `MutableState<Boolean>`, I've set `val expanded = remember {mutableStateOf(true)} and later expanded.value = !listState.isScrollInProgress ` just in case you want to change the answer. Thanks!!